# sun.rmi.transport.tcp.readTimeout not effective

Tags: rmi

I have set sun.rmi.transport.tcp.readTimeout as a JVM parameter in the configuration file of my product which is available as a service. I have set a very minimal value of 1000ms, which means all operations done using my CLI that would take more than 1second should fail with the exception     java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection

Please let me know if I have missed any other parameter which is required to make this work. I want to set a timeout of say 10 minutes. But I want to set a really low value to confirm that the timeout is effective.
Are the parameters java.rmi.activation.port and java.rmi.server.hostname related to this?
Please refer http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=246620.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.test

Answer (score 1):

> which means all operations done using
> my CLI that would take more than
> 1second should fail

No it doesn't. A client-side timeout would do that, but `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.readTimeout` controls the read timeout *at the server,* which in turn has an effect on connection pooling. To control client-side read timeouts you need to set the undocumented property called (I think) `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout` at each client JVM.